# ATMega328 AU bootloader burning issue using Nano

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, atmega328, bootloader

We are trying to burn bootloader into ATMega328P-AU SMD. We have taken the reference of the **[link](http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut6.php)** and did the same. We checked wire connections and all looks fine and we tried with two chip with two separate boards and we got same result.

But we tried many times and got the same error as follows,

Could someone help us on this?

```
    /data/install/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/data/install/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDA:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/data/install/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/sankar/.avrduderc"

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x15
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x15
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x14

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x02

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
         Hardware Version: 4238814
         Firmware Version: 24405360.0
         Topcard         : STK502
         Vtarget         : 1.8 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: stk500_initialize(): (b) protocol error, expect=0x10, resp=0x01
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Error while burning bootloader.
```

Comment: did you research the error?

Comment: in your output two avrdude processes run parallel. let one finish before starting again. do you use "Arduino as ISP"? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Comment: @Juraj yes. We uploaded ArduinoISP to nano first, then we change options to Arduino as ISP to burn bootloader. When that happens only we get error.

Comment: try a capacitor to suppress the auto-reset of Nano. in the link in my first comment see the instructions for Mega as programmer on how to add the capacitor. other option is to make this change in programmers.txt https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/pull/56/commits/a901b081aed0c60e97777c9c92350d354b721094

Comment: @Juraj: It’s working fine after changing the programmers.txt. Can you put it as answer so that I will accept..?

Comment: @per1234, this is for you to answer